# How to clear $Error in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to clear the $Error variable that tracks errors in a PowerShell session?

If so, how do you do it?

I have tried:
`$error.clear`

In the PowerShell ISE on Windows 7 and the $Error array is still populated.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

It is a .NET method call so you need parens:

```
$error.clear()
```

Comment: PowerShell is *not* case-sensitive.  If it were, it would be `$Error.Clear()`.  :-)

Comment: Shouldn't you [preserve case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/strongly-encouraged-development-guidelines?view=powershell-7#make-cmdlets-case-insensitive-and-case-preserving-sc04) if you can though?

Comment: @n00dles The linked article is about designing cmdlets to treat case appropriately.  It is not about case throughout the use of PowerShell.  It does not matter for the majority of commands you give it.  `$eRRor.CLEAR()` is fine.

Comment: Why doesn't the obvious `Clear-Variable -Name "error" -Force` work?